# My bot is sending multiple messages for 1 request

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

What the code is supposed to do is make the bot read the words "Good bot" and respond with a message saying "thanks!". The problem is that its writing thanks two times instead of one and I don't know how to fix it. I'm using JDA-3.8.1_450-withDependencies as my library.

[image]

Example:

```
Me: Good bot
bot: thanks!
bot: thanks!
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code as text. There's no easy way to try code in an image ourselves, nor can we we copy snippets of it into our answers, and it won't show up in future Google searches. See also: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/68587)

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Showing code is a lot more helpful than describing it. Please [edit] your question to include your code, sample input and output, and any error messages. Tell us what you expect to happen as well as what's actually happening. This will help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello**, this answer is simple:

It is because you have a for-loop for every argument of the message and "Good bot" has 2 arguments ("Good" and "bot") You just have to remove the for-loop, now to code runs only 1 time because you send only 1 message to the bot.

Have fun, I hope I could help you!